# get the form attached to a spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm working with the "new" version of google SS.

I'd like to get the form attached to the spreadsheet I'm in, like this:

```
function findFormURL() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return ss.getFormUrl();
}
```

However, this function does not work yet in the new version.

Anyway,it gives the URL of the form, which is interesting, but I'd like to have the form ID or object so I can then work with it, change some stuff etc. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed annoying but there is a possible way to get around this missing feature using the drive search capabilities... I tested it with the code below and it worked.

I agree that this is far from ideal and requires to have a form that has the same unique name as your spreadsheet but it's better than nothing.

```
function getFormTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nameToSearch = ss.getName();
  Logger.log('title contains "'+nameToSearch+'"');
  var forms = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "'+nameToSearch+'"');
  while (forms.hasNext()){
    var formDoc = forms.next();
    Logger.log(formDoc.getMimeType());
    if(formDoc.getMimeType()=='application/vnd.google-apps.form'){ 
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log('formDoc = '+formDoc);
  var form = FormApp.openById(formDoc.getId());
  var items = form.getItems();
  for(var i in items){
    Logger.log(items[i].getTitle()+'  '+items[i].getType());
  }
}
```

Comment: this might work, Actually my form & ss are supposed to have the same name. I'll try it tomorrow.